# Бинарное дерево с несколькими вложениями

Tags: c#

Меня интересует бинарное дерево такого типа как на картинке.
Поможет кто нибудь с реализацией? У меня возникла проблема с поиском нужного значения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TreeNode first = new TreeNode
            {
                Left = null,
                Right = null,
                Center = new Tree
                {
                    Value = "First",
                    Node = new TreeNode
                    {
                        Right = new Tree
                        {
                            Value = "Right",
                            Node = new TreeNode
                            {
                                Center = new Tree
                                {
                                    Value = "Right second"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class TreeNode
    {
        public Tree Left { get; set; }
        public Tree Right { get; set; }
        public Tree Center { get; set; }
    }

    public class Tree
    {
        public TreeNode Node { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Без кода ваших попыток реализации такой структуры данных маловероятно, что вам кто-то поможет

Comment: Да хотя бы без внятного описания. Что значит "с несколькими вложениями"?

Comment: Добавил код. Мне нужна подобная структура и возникает проблемы с поиском. Данное дерево задаваться должно пользователем и сколько там будет вложений мне неизвестно и делать бесконечных циклов тоже не хочется.

Comment: Бинарное дерево имеет только два внутренних узла, у вас уже не бинарное дерево. Если дерево обычное, как у вас, то путь только один - перебрать все значения. Городить циклы не надо, пусть каждый узел сам ищет у себя значение в TreeNode, реализуя метод Find. UPD: как раз дали ответ, как это примерно сделать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Напишите рекурсивный поиск. Дерево у вас, правда, не бинарное, раз в каждом узле задано 3 поддерева. Но примерно так:

```
public class TreeNode
{
    public Tree Left { get; set; }
    public Tree Right { get; set; }
    public Tree Center { get; set; }

    public bool Find(string value)
    {
        return (Left?.Find(value) ?? false) || (Center?.Find(value) ?? false) || (Right?.Find(value) ?? false);
    }
}

public class Tree
{
    public TreeNode Node { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public bool Find(string value)
    {
        return this.Value == value || (Node?.Find(value) ?? false);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(first.Find("Right")); // true
Console.WriteLine(first.Find("Some"));  // false
```

Comment: Огромная благодарность за помощь.